# How do I pass a model to a partial view and load a specific record?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am still relatively new to MVC and am finding every new concept to be a struggle, so please forgive me if this is an overly simple concept or the question has been asked many times before (I tried to find other examples).

I have several modals that can be called from my shared layout using jQuery's "dialog." Each modal is simply a DIV with a partial view attached to it like this:

```
<div id="JoinDialog" title="Join the Contractor Network" style="display: none;">
    @Html.Partial("_JoinPartial")
</div>
```

And is called like this:

```
    $(".ClickToJoin").click(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#JoinDialog").dialog({ width: "auto", height: "auto"});
        });
    });
```

I have added a "Profile" modal to the layout in which I would like to insert the user's data into the INPUT values. To do that, I presume that I will need to pass in a model, and load the data I want via the controller. Since I currently have this partial view in the "Shared" folder, I assume I will also need to move it to one of my view folders where I can attach it to a controller?

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I currently have this partial view in the "Shared" folder, I
>   assume I will also need to move it to one of my view folders where I
>   can attach it to a controller?

No there is no need for you to move the partial view to the controller folder. You can use the partial view from the shared folder itself (View Engine also looks at Shared folder to find a matching view). Here goes the sample example -

Lets say you have a model like this -

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then you have an action to return the partial view from the shared folder -

```
    public ActionResult GetPartial()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.Name = "Rami";
        return PartialView("TestPartial", model);
    }
```

Then have the partial view in the Shared folder like this -

```
@model YouModelNamespace.MyModel
<div>@Model.Name</div>
```

Then on the actual page, you can have following code -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@{
    Html.RenderAction("GetPartial");
}
```

That will display the result from the partial view on the page as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you have to render a View (or a Partial View), asp.net mvc has some default orders to find it. First asp.net mvc will search the respective views' folder of the controller you are executing and if it was not found, asp.net mvc search on the Shared folder. So, if you have a view called `_JoinPartial` on the `Views/Product` (for sample) folder and shared folder, it will priorize the View folder. Sometimes you get a exception that views was not found, in there message you can see all places where asp.net mvc find it, for sample:

[image]

In your case, the controller could return a Partial View

```
public ActionResult GetJoinPartial()
{
    return PartialView("_JoinPartial");
}
```

Since you have on the View folder, it will use it, instead it will use the partialView on the Shared folder.